# Unknown network added to "Authorized Networks" after cloning GCP Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL second generation Cloud SQL instance in GCP which was recently cloned.  This source instance has one Authorized Network, which I added.  Upon inspection of the clone, however, I found that there was a second, unknown IP added to the Authorized Networks list.  Is this an artifact of the cloning process?  I don't have any reason to believe my account has been compromised.

Comment: Can you please specify the name of the added network?

Comment: The network was unnamed and unfortunately I was so quick to delete that I didn't think to record the IP.